# Swift convert UIImage to 24-bit RGB with no alpha channel

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift4, 24-bit

I'd like to convert the UIImage to a 24-bit RGB with no inbetween 32-bit RGBA buffer.

I tried this, but it does not work (bytes is all zero) :

```
public func pixelsRGB() -> [UInt8]? {

    let size = self.size
    let dataSize = size.width * size.height * 3
    var pixelData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(dataSize))
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let context = CGContext(data: &pixelData,
                            width: Int(size.width),
                            height: Int(size.height),
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: 3 * Int(size.width),
                            space: colorSpace,
                            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)
    guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else {
        return nil
    }
    context?.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

    return pixelData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but since I struggled with it too I thought it'd be good to add some of what I found.

As answered on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704577/is-it-possible-to-make-a-nsbitmapimagerep-with-24-bpp-and-no-alpha-channel), Quartz doesn't support a 24-bit RGB image.  See supported formats [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBEAGHH).  @matt answered this question also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974385/unable-to-get-a-valid-cgcontext-when-using-any-rgb-color-space)

I suspect it's failing to create the CGContext and returning nil for *context*.  Then it never writes to the context and just returns the values you initialized for your byte buffer.

If you change your line:

```
bytesPerRow: 3 * Int(size.width),
```

to:

```
bytesPerRow: 4 * Int(size.width), //to accommodate the non-existing alpha channel
```

you'll get a valid context and be able to use it to draw in.  Kind of a pain, but that's how I got around it.